# Parsing an column containing integers

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am writing a query that pulls 50 fields from 12 sub-queries in the FROM statement. Each sub query is left-joined on two fields the Item SKU and Brand ID. However there is one table where the Brand ID is concatenated in a comma delimited column.

My problem is that I am having trouble parsing this column so that I can use it as a foreign key to join to the other sub-queries. I tried setting the column = to a variable and then using the String_Split function, but was getting the error 'No column selected for column 1' in the query. If anyone has any suggestions of how to parse this data into a NEW row so that SKU that has multiple brands associated to it each has a row showing that SKU and Brand. I have added a screen shot of the data that needs to be parsed. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: We need to see your code. What would the expected results be for the above? What's the actual sample data? I expect there to be some sort of ID field to go along with this concatenated list of brands.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Does it have STRING_SPLIT ? If so that is super simple. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Isn't [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#b-split-comma-separated-value-string-in-a-column) on the MSSQL docs exactly what you're trying to do?

```
+-----------+--------------------+----------------------------+
| ProductId |        Name        |            Tags            |
+-----------+--------------------+----------------------------+
|         1 | Full-Finger Gloves | clothing,road,touring,bike |
|         2 | LL Headset         | bike                       |
|         3 | HL Mountain Frame  | bike,mountain              |
+-----------+--------------------+----------------------------+
```

gets transformed into (note the change in the column name!)

```
+-----------+--------------------+----------+
| ProductId |        Name        |  value   |
+-----------+--------------------+----------+
|         1 | Full-Finger Gloves | clothing |
|         1 | Full-Finger Gloves | road     |
|         1 | Full-Finger Gloves | touring  |
|         1 | Full-Finger Gloves | bike     |
|         2 | LL Headset         | bike     |
|         3 | HL Mountain Frame  | bike     |
|         3 | HL Mountain Frame  | mountain |
+-----------+--------------------+----------+
```

using

```
SELECT ProductId, Name, value  
FROM Product  
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Tags, ',');
```

Since you didn't share any code, it's impossible for me to be more specific... but this example really seems to me should be the piece you're missing.